# EJBCA on Docker: use environmental variables in .properties files

Tags: ant, docker-container, pki, docker-image, ejbca

I am trying to configure EJBCA 6.15.2.1 on Wildfly 12.0.0.Final inside a Docker container with the help of EJBCA .properties files. In `$EJBCA_HOME/conf/externalra-gui.properties.sample` there is a comment showing that one of the default settings is: `appserver.home=${env.APPSRV_HOME}`. I tried to set other options in a similar way, e. g. in `database.properties`: `database.datasource=${env.WF_DATASRC}`.

I run `ant clean deployear` and it didn't deploy my EJBCA instance properly at first - server.log showed that there is no datasource under the name `"${env.WF_DATASRC}"`. It proceeded correctly after I'd changed the line to: `database.datasource=ejbcads`, which is the exact value of the variable and the name of the data source inside the WildFly server.

I get similar errors during further installation steps. Is there another way of setting EJBCA configuration using environment variables?